# Automapper child mapping with entity in the middle

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have the following entity structure that I want to map to a Dto

**Context Entities**

```
public class CallPoint
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public ICollection {UserCallPoint} UserCallPoints {get; set;}
}

public class UserCallPoint
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public CallPoint CallPoint {get; set;}
    public User User {get; set;
}

public class User
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Email {get; set;}
    public ICollection<UserCallPoint> UserCallPoints {get; set;
}
```

**DTO**

```
public class CallPointDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<UserDto> Users { get; set; }
}

public class UserDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<CallPointDto> CallPoints { get; set; }
}
```

So basically I have a many to many mapping but there is an entity in between that acts as a lookup table basically. How do I do this mapping? I am currently just looping and mapping like below but it is far too slow

```
    private List<CallPointDto> MapCallPoint(List<CallPoint> callPoints)
    {
        List<CallPointDto> callPointDtos = new List<CallPointDto>();
        foreach (var callPoint in callPoints)
        {
            var callPointDto = _mapper.Map<CallPointDto>(callPoint);
            callPointDto.Users = new List<UserDto>();
            foreach (var item in callPoint.UserCallPoints)
            {
                UserDto userDto = _mapper.Map<UserDto>(item.User);
                callPointDto.Users.Add(userDto);
            }
            callPointDtos.Add(callPointDto);
        }
        return callPointDtos;
    }
```

How would I do this with a Custom Resolver?

Comment: Do i see it right that `CallPoints` on your `UserDto` isn't set? Is this is intended or should it be set? When it should be set, there is the possibility that you need to call all `CallPoint`, `UserCallPoint` and `User` from the DB, because they all could be connected. And do you really looking for a CustomResolver or just the right way to map this?

Comment: Basically if I try to map it with FromMember() I get stuck in a loop as UserDto has many to many with CallPointDto, so if I set one it loops forever

Comment: This didn't answer any of my questions^^

Comment: @Rabban sorry.If you set CallPoints on UserDto, wont you have a recursive set scenario happen? It doesn't need to be a CustomResolver I just need it to map to Dto.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you the answer that you are looking for because of the problem that the n:m relation could run endlessly. But i would suggest you to work with different sub-DTOs like this:

```
public class CallPointBaseDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class CallPointDto : CallPointBaseDto
{
    public List<UserBaseDto> Users { get; set; }
}

public class UserBaseDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
public class UserDto : UserBaseDto
{
    public List<CallPointBaseDto> CallPoints { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
cfg.CreateMap<CallPoint, CallPointDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Users, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.UserCallPoints.Select(ucp => ucp.User)));
cfg.CreateMap<User, UserBaseDto>();
```

The downside of this, is of course, you don't have the CallPoints in your UserBaseDto, but if you need it, you can call this User explicitly and map it the other way.